# Blockquotes duplicating quotes on span tags

Tags: html, css

I have this css aplied to my page:

```
blockquote ::before {
  content: "“";
}

blockquote ::after {
  content: "”";
}
```

It is used to put blockquote between quotes, however when I am using a blockquote with a span tag inside I got duplicated quotes. (All the html is generated by a wysiwyg editor)

[image]

Image html:

```
<blockquote>
<p>blockquote</p>
</blockquote>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<blockquote>
<h1>blockquote</h1>
</blockquote>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<blockquote>
<p><span style="font-size:20px;">blockquote</span></p>
</blockquote>
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: That isn't CSS. Presumably it is some other language and you are generating CSS from it. What does the CSS look like?

Comment: sorry, I posted it wrong. Now I have edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
blockquote::before {
  content: "“";
}
blockquote::after {
  content: "”";
}
```

If you use a space, the selectors match `::before` and `::after` of all descendants of `blockquote`.

Without space, the  rules will only match `::before` and `::after` of `blockquote`, so you won't have duplicate quotes, and it will work even if there is no descendant.

Comment: Or, if you really want it applied to the *immediate* descendant(s) (e.g. just the `p` around the `span`), `blockquote > ::before {...}`, etc. Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/qDhyG

Answer (score 1):

```
blockquote ::before

          ^
```

You have a space there. This is [a *descendant combinator*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

You aren't putting quotes before and after the blockquote, you are putting them before and after *every element inside it* (i.e. the paragraphs *and* the spans).

Remove the space: `blockquote::before` and `blockquote::after`.